# Subdomains with Office add-in AppDomains

Tags: office365, add-in, office-js

Does anyone know if wildcards are allowed in [AppDomain](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/appdomain) elements for Office add-in [manifests](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/add-in-manifests)? I am looking to allow all subdomains and hoping something like the following will work:

```
<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://*.acme.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

I have seen a few old posts which say no but also some suggestions that this will change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present, the Office add-in doesn’t support wildcards to set the trust domains. As a workaround, we need to specific all the domain the app trust with full path. And if this feature is your required, you can try to submit the feedback from link below:

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks I've made the suggestion [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/13314972-support-wildcards-for-appdomains-in-office-add-in) if anyone else wants to give it an upvote.